# To insert the images as the element of the matrix

Tags: matlab

I have four images and also 4 by 1 matrix. I want to keep each image as the each of the elements of the given matrix. I tried with imagecell, but I could not process it further.

Comment: Can you show us your code so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data structure that will hold the images will be a cell array, which we declare with:

```
image_cell = cell(4, 1);
```

Let's suppose you had the i'th image. You would add the image in using:

```
image_cell(i) = image_i;
```

where `image_i` was the image you wanted to add.

Comment: Or directly: `image_cell = {image_1; image_2; image_3; image_4}`

Comment: @Matt Thanks for your help. I did that and its working fine. I have another issue i.e., I need to perform multiplication of this cell array with its tranjugate. How should I do it?

Comment: For each element, `image_cell(i)`, if I understand the transjugate correctly, you can simply do `image_cell(i)';` According to this (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ctranspose.html), a regular transpose does the complex conjugate transpose, which I believe is what you want.